# Relationships are shown twice

Tags: relationships

I am using CiviCRM 4.5.5 with Drupal 7.

When I go to add a relationship the  custom relationships show up twice.

[image: Image of Relationships Showing up Twice]

Please help.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 5):

As per the code the select list loads all relationship types of corresponding Contact's contact Type. So for instance [Employee of (Individual type), Employer of (Organization Type)] Relationship Type(RT), if you are going to add relationship for Individual Contact A then on you will only see 'Employee of' (not 'Employer of') RT.

In your case "other projector contributor' and 'other project contributor is' are both related to same contact type thats why you are able to see both on select list.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about fact that there is both "other projector contributor' and 'other project contributor is'? then that is expected. it is showing you both ends of the relationship - same as it would with parent-child.